# Looking for books covering signed measures in detail

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, signed-measures

so I am looking for good text books that treat signed measures, integration thereof and total variation etc. In particular also for finitely additive signed measures.

I have found Dunford and Schwartz a little bit too general in that they dont necessarily consider (signed) measures but more generally set functions.

I would also like the book to be as standard in notation and the used concepts as possible.

So can you give me any suggestions for text books?

Comment: Measure Theory by Paul Halmos.

Comment: thank you. Unfortunately I dont like the fact that he uses sigma rings instead of sigma algebras to define measures

Comment: Rudin Real and complex analysis has a chapter on this

Comment: Hi i think he treats complex measures that he requires to be finite and also dorsnt talk about the finitely Additive case,no?

Comment: Aliprantis & Border might come close to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I found "Real analysis - modern techniques and their applications" by G. Folland to be very instructive, clear and comprehensive. He also covers all the mentioned subjects in detail.

Comment: but he does not treat finitely additive signed measures right?

Comment: I do not believe so. It seems I misunderstood you, sorry

Comment: thank you non the less